# Woocommerce Checkout Page Blank after Update to 2.3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This happened after upgrading to woocommerce 2.3

when i move from the cart page to the checkout page the page does not load at all.

I see in view source that it loads a few meta tags and jquery before it just cuts out.

Google Chrome console is showing me that 
GET https://www.prodecotech.com/prodecotech-checkout/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Is your theme compatible with woocommerce? otherwise you have to make some changes like described here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Comment: Can you show logfiles? I can reproduce your error, btw.

Comment: It's not, thanks for the suggestion I just added woocommerce.php aned I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing in Logs:[Thu Feb 12 09:32:06 2015] [error] [client 192.28.0.16] Failed loading /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so:  /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string

Comment: ahh enabled debug mode: Fatal error: Call to undefined method WooCommerce::add_inline_js() in /home4/prodecot/public_html/twopointo/wp-content/plugins/codecanyon-4232273-store-pickup-google-maps-woocommerce-wordpress/shipping-store-pickup.php on line 1842

Comment: Obviously the issue was with plugin Store Pickup v2.1.0, deactivated plugin and page now works fine. Thanks for helping me hash this out.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with plugin Store Pickup v2.1.0, deactivated plugin and Checkout page now works fine.

Comment: For everyone else, remember to [test in a staging environment](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/testing-updates-using-a-staging-environment/)

Comment: and/or make a backup before updating your software!

Comment: At least that. But if you bork everything in staging... it's only staging!